# M-type potassium channels by muscarinic receptors

Tags: neuroscience

How does the closure of M-type potassium channels by muscarinic receptors result in increased excitation of the target neuron?

Answer (score 1):

Closing of the channel through muscarinic receptors involves activation of phospoholipase C and depletion of membrane phosphatidyilinositol-4,5-bisphospate which is needed for the channel to stay open. Once the channel is closed,  potassium, which is a positive ion accumulates inside the cell eventually depolarizing it or lowering its threshold for activation. Thus, blocking the extrusion of K ions results in excitation of the target neuron.

See this for more:
Brown, D. A., and Constanti, A. (1980). Intracellular observations on the effects of muscarinic agonists on rat sympathetic neurones. Br. J. Pharmacol. 70, 593–608.